# sql group by is duplicating results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have trying to create a list of manufactures with a count.

This is my query

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT manufacture, count(*) AS count
                                      FROM listed_watches
                                      GROUP BY manufacture');
```

But when i do print_r, its duplicating the results. It is showing "manufacture" and "count" but its also showing [0] and [1], how come?

I just want it to show [manufacture], [count]

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [manufacture] => Audemars Piguet
            [0] => Audemars Piguet
            [count] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [manufacture] => Bell and Ross
            [0] => Bell and Ross
            [count] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [manufacture] => Bulova
            [0] => Bulova
            [count] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: How are you fetching records?

Comment: Its not related to SQL Group By how you are fetching results in php provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can use by default this fetching method in the initialization of your connection with :

```
$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE] = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;
```

Comment: YES :D this works. Could you explain a bit why this happened?

Comment: The default Fetch_Mode is PDO::FETCH_BOTH, which return duplicates values (by column name and by index). Why this, I don't know... but you can read some informations here : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php